# Adding elements to a multidimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I currently have an ArrayList (mapArray) such that each element of the ArrayList contains a String such as:

```
################
```

So the ArrayList could look as such:

```
################
#..............#
#........G.....#
#..............#
################
```

So each element is:

Element 0:

```
################
```

Element 1:

```
#..............#
```

Element 2:

```
#........G.....#
```

Element 3:

```
#..............#
```

Element 4:

```
################
```

How would i go about adding this data to a multidimensional array so that the first element would be the row number and the second element would be the character e.g. 2DArray[2][9] = G

So far i have

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        String element = mapArray.get(i);
        elementSplit = element.split("(?!^)");
        for(int j = 0; j < elementSplit.length; j++){
            TwoDArray [i][j] = [i][elementSplit[j]];
        }
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for any help :)

And sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0):

Your can do something like this:

```
char[][] TwoDArray = new char[mapArray.size()][];

for (int i=0; i<mapArray.size(); i++) {
    TwoDArray[i] = mapArray.get(i).toCharArray();
}
```

Be aware that, in your case, the letter G is the position TwoDArray[2][9]

Answer (score 0):

This method converts a String ArrayList to char[][]. Hope this helps.

```
public static char[][] to2DCharArray(ArrayList<String> mapArray) {
    char[][] c = new char[mapArray.size()][mapArray.get(0).length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < mapArray.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < mapArray.get(i).length(); j++) {
            c[i][j] = mapArray.get(i).charAt(j);
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```