# Syntax error on token "=", Expression expected after this token

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, syntax-error

I am getting an error message which i do not under stand, my code is as follows:

```
public void generate2DArray(ArrayList<String> mapArray, int lineNumber)
{
    lineNumber = lineNumber - 2;
    String [] elementSplit = null;
    char TwoDArray [][] = new char[lineNumber][];
    for(int i = 0; i < mapArray.size(); i++){
        elementSplit = (mapArray.get(i)).split("(?!^)");
        for(int j = 0; j < elementSplit.length; j++){
            TwoDArray [i][j] = [i][elementSplit[j]];
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elementSplit));
    }
}
```

The error occurs during:

```
TwoDArray [i][j] = [i][elementSplit[j]];
```

Where i get the following error:

```
Syntax error on token "=", Expression expected after this token
```

Can anyone advise on this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: `TwoDArray [i][j] = elementSplit[j][i];` ??

Comment: String [] elementSplit = null; 
it is just one dimension array

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but element split is a one dimensional array

Comment: What exactly do you expect / want `[i][elementSplit[j]]` to do?

Comment: String elementSplit[][];
TwoDArray [i][j] = elementSplit[i][j]

Comment: Essentially i would like it to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776772/adding-elements-to-a-multidimensional-array/21777372?noredirect=1#21777372

Comment: try to assign the array variable correctly.
TwoDArray [i][j] = [i][elementSplit[j]]; is not correct

Comment: It seems like you're trying to output 3 dimensions into 2 dimensions, which obviously won't work, at least not without a bit of advanced indexing. The 3 dimensions are: `ArrayList` (of `String`s), `String[]` (from the `split`), `String` (in the `String[]`) -> `char` (in `TwoDArray`).

Comment: Check my Edited Answer. It is a sample for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

you have error because TwoArray[i][j] is a char just one character not string .

And elementSplit[j] is a String, so you must using this form

```
TwoDArray [i][j]= elementSplit[j].charAt(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follwing is a sample for your needs.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ALTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add("################");
        al.add("#..............#");
        al.add("#........G.....#");
        al.add("#..............#");
        al.add("################");
        char[][] twoDarray = get2DArray(al);
    }

    private static char[][] get2DArray(ArrayList<String> mapArray) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        char [] elementSplit = null;
        char twoDarray [][] = new char[mapArray.size()][];
        for(int i = 0; i < mapArray.size(); i++){
            elementSplit = (mapArray.get(i)).toCharArray();
            twoDarray [i] = elementSplit;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elementSplit));
        }
        return twoDarray;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code with sample with String array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem your having is that you are putting things into you 2D array wrong.

`TwoDArray [i][j]` is a single location so can only hold a single number/character etc.
You are trying to put the value `i` and the value of `elementSplit[j]` in the same location.

So your line:

```
TwoDArray [i][j] = [i][elementSplit[j]];
```

is incorrectly implemented.

You can only do:

```
TwoDArray [i][j] = i;
```

or

```
TwoDArray [i][j] = elementSplit[j];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
TwoDArray [i][j] = [i][elementSplit[j]];
```

to

```
TwoDArray [i][j] = elementSplit[j].charAt(0);
```

Comment: Right Dukeling, changed elementSplit[j] to elementSplit.charAt(j), thx.

Comment: Thanks very much but i get the error: Cannot invoke charAt(int) on the array type String[]

Comment: Edited to elementSplit[j].charAt(0);